# path without the document

Tags: path, document, host

How can I get a document path without the documents name? For example:

```
window.document.location
```

gives me:  `http://host.com/lorem/ipsum/document.php`
and I need to get only: `http://host.com/lorem/ipsum/`.

Will be greatful for help.

Comment: regular expression or a simple javascript. It has nothing to do with `jQuery`

Comment: Alright, I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var loc = location.href;
loc = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = window.document.location;
path = path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

Comment: Thanks. Computer locked up on me about the time I saw the typo.